# Display next available date on shop page for woocommerce bookable products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I use the Woocommerce bookable products plugin. I want to display the next available date (earliest available date) for each bookable product right on the shop page - which has the image, title and the price. This would allow customers to choose the right product based on availability without having to go into detail pages for each product.

The below code prints a custom text to each product. But, how do I echo the next available date instead of "my custom text"

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woo_show_excerpt_shop_page', 5 );
function woo_show_excerpt_shop_page() {
global $product;
echo "my custom text";
}
```